# Why/when is numpy.equal() 10x faster when working with x.T.copy() instead of x.T?

Tags: python, numpy, performance

**Context:** I made the following observations when trying to optimize my code for speed. It involves the use of large square matrices with up to 3.6e9 elements (assuming I can speed it up sufficiently ...).

**Observations:** Consider a square numpy array `x`. Doing `x == x.T` takes significantly longer than `x == x`, `x == x.T.copy()`, or even `x.T == x.T`. If `x` has 1e8 elements, `x == x.T` is 10x times slower than all other variants (on my system), including doing `x.T.copy()`.

**Question:** I suppose that the speed loss is related to the fact that `x.T` [returns a view of x](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html#numpy.ndarray.transpose) ? I am however surprised at the amplitude of the loss. I was even more surprised to realize that working with two transposed arrays, or with copies of the transposed array appears to have very little overhead.

I am now left wondering if **I should start systematically copying my transposed numpy arrays** (i.e. use `x.T.copy()` instead of `x.T`) to gain significant speed in my code ?

Is this expected behavior from numpy, or could there be something off with my setup (incl. the underlying BLAS/LAPACK) ?

**MWE:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np


def time_loop(a, b, niter=10):

    time = 0
    for _ in range(niter):
        start = datetime.now()
        _ = (a == b)
        time += (datetime.now()-start).total_seconds()

    return time/niter


very_start = datetime.now()

for size in [100, 1000, 10000, 15000, 20000]:
    print(f'\nsize: {size}')

    # Create the array once to not influence the timings
    x = np.random.rand(size, size)
    # Create the transpose too already
    x_t = x.T
    x_t_c = x.T.copy()

    # Case 1: straight vs straight
    print(f' x == x: {time_loop(x, x):.6f}s')

    # Case 2: straight vs transposed
    print(f' x == x.T: {time_loop(x, x_t):.6f}s')

    # Case 3: straight vs transposed.copy()
    print(f' x == x.T.copy(): {time_loop(x, x_t_c):.6f}s')

    # Case 4: transposed vs transposed
    print(f' x.T == x.T: {time_loop(x_t, x_t):.6f}s')


print(f'\nTotal runtime: {(datetime.now()-very_start).total_seconds():.1f}s')
```

returns

```
size: 100
 x == x: 0.000005s
 x == x.T: 0.000010s
 x == x.T.copy(): 0.000004s
 x.T == x.T: 0.000004s

size: 1000
 x == x: 0.000412s
 x == x.T: 0.001698s
 x == x.T.copy(): 0.000887s
 x.T == x.T: 0.000396s

size: 10000
 x == x: 0.070157s
 x == x.T: 1.024655s
 x == x.T.copy(): 0.099336s
 x.T == x.T: 0.067587s

size: 15000
 x == x: 0.151993s
 x == x.T: 2.561973s
 x == x.T.copy(): 0.223449s
 x.T == x.T: 0.152339s

size: 20000
 x == x: 0.280847s
 x == x.T: 6.938656s
 x == x.T.copy(): 0.396516s
 x.T == x.T: 0.275735s

Total runtime: 141.5s
```

on my system:
OS X, Python 3.10.6 via miniconda/conda-forge, numpy 1.23.4

```
In [111]: np.show_config()
blas_info:
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/Some/secret/path']
    include_dirs = ['/Some/secret/path']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/Some/secret/path']
    include_dirs = ['/Some/secret/path']
    language = c
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/Some/secret/path']
    language = f77
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/Some/secret/path']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/Some/secret/path']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

Comment: `x.T` is a `view`, with different `strides`.  For 2d array that's an `order F` array.  For smallish arrays I wouldn't expect  this big of a difference, but you may be large enough that memory isues are chewing up time (paging, caching, etc)